# How to output 'passed' if a diff command results in no difference in bash?

Tags: c, shell, testing, automated-tests, diff

I am writing a shell script that loops over my ./tests directory and uses the unix diff command to compare .in and .out files against each other for my C program. Here is my shell script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

count=0

# Loop through test files
for t in tests/*.in; do
echo '================================================================'
echo '                         Test' $count
echo '================================================================'
echo 'Testing' $t '...'

# Output results to (test).res
(./snapshot < $t) > "${t%.*}.res"

# Test with diff against the (test).out files
diff "${t%.*}.res" "${t%.*}.out"

echo '================================================================'
echo '                         Memcheck
echo '================================================================'

# Output results to (test).res
(valgrind ./snapshot < $t) > "${t%.*}.res"

count=$((count+1))

done
```

My question is how can I add an if statement to the script that will output 'passed' if the diff command results in no difference? e.g.

pseudo code:

```
if ((diff res_file out_file) == '') {
    echo 'Passed'
} else {
    printf "Failed\n\n"
    diff res_file out_file
}
```

Comment: I have read somewhere, for loops shouldn't be used to iterate through files in a directory. but can't recall where.

Comment: Do you know why or what would be the appropriate tool to use instead?

Comment: The article i read suggested a `while` loop. But you may neglect these comments unless somebody confirm it or I am able to find the source

Comment: @sjsam Did you maybe mean [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)? `for` and globbing is fine.

Comment: @BenjaminW.; You naiiled it .. This is the stuff i have been searching for long...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get and check the exit code from the diff command. diff has an exit code of 0 if no differences were found.

```
diff ...
ret=$?

if [[ $ret -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "passed."
else
    echo "failed."
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @jstills worked for me however I modified it slightly and thought I'd post my result as an answer too to help others

Once I understood that diff has an exit code of 0 I modified my code to this. It checks if diff exits with 0 or >1 for each difference if I understand correctly. My code then sends the output of diff to /dev/null so it won't be displayed to stdout and I then do my check and print passed or failed to the stdout and if failed the differences with sdiff which display differences side by side.

```
if diff "${t%.*}.res" "${t%.*}.out" >/dev/null; then
    printf "Passed\n"
else
    printf "Failed\n"
    sdiff "${t%.*}.res" "${t%.*}.out"
fi
```

Comment: You might wish to change  `>/dev/null` to  `>/dev/null 2>&1`. In current scenario, diff errors will still be dumped to stdout. See [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-redirect-output-and-errors-to-devnull/)

Comment: @sjsam Good addition, added to my script.